# React Redux Firebase Not loading props until refresh after auth

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication

After the user logs in props are not loaded unless the user refreshes the page, why might this be?

Here is the dashboard they get Redirected to after login, which props are then loaded from Firebase using mapstatetoprops/connect.

I have been checking other threads but nothing seems to relate to my issue or come close to fixing it, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect, isLoaded, isEmpty } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import ProjectList from '../Projects/ProjectList'
import { compose } from 'redux'
import CreateProject from '../Projects/CreateProject'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import NavComponent from './NavComponent'
import MainSidebar from'./MainSidebar'
import SearchMain from './Search/SearchMain'
import Notifications from './Notifications'


class Dashboard extends Component {
    state = {
        admins: '',
        isLoaded: false
    }

    render() {

    const {projects, auth, profile, organisations, innerprojects, comments, notifications} = this.props;
    const searchMain = auth.uid ? <SearchMain profile={profile} comments={comments} innerprojects={innerprojects} projects={projects}/>  : null
    const notificationMain = auth.uid ? <Notifications profile={profile} notifications={notifications} /> : null


        if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />

        if (isLoaded(auth) || !isEmpty(auth)) {
        return (
        <>
        {profile.email ? <NavComponent  notifications={notifications} comments={comments} innerprojects={innerprojects} projects={projects} auth={auth} profile={profile}/> : null }

          <div className="container project-details-container">
            <div className="row home-header-row">
                <MainSidebar projects={projects} profile={profile}/>
                <div className="col-lg-9 dash-section section">

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-10">
                            {searchMain}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 notifications-col">
                            {projects? notificationMain : null}
                            <CreateProject admins={this.state.admins} organisations={organisations}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {this.props.projects? <ProjectList auth={auth} projects={projects} authID={auth.uid} profile={profile}/> : null }

                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </>
        )
        }else{
            return <p>Loading</p>
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
        comments: state.firestore.ordered.comments,
        innerprojects: state.firestore.ordered.innerprojects,
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        profile: state.firebase.profile,
        notifications: state.firestore.ordered.notifications,
        organisations: state.firestore.ordered.organisations
    }
}

export default compose(
connect(mapStateToProps),
firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'projects', orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc']},
    { collection: 'comments', orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc']},
    { collection: 'innerprojects', orderBy: ['createdAt', 'desc']},
    { collection: 'organisations', orderBy: ['time', 'desc'] },
    { collection: 'notifications', limit: 5, orderBy: ['time', 'desc']}
    ])
    )(Dashboard)
```

It looks like theirs something wrong with state.firestore, state.firebase is pulling data correctly. Please see below screenshot to see what props are loading and which ones are not.

[dev console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVKJu.png)

Comment: First of all please format your code, so it becomes better readable

Comment: Should be better now

Comment: I have found a solution, added to the bottom of the post if anyone else needs help

Comment: Great to hear that you found the solution. Please post it as an **answer**, instead of an edit to your question. Self-answers are encouraged here on Stack Overflow, make it easier for others to see you've already been helped, and allow you to earn reputation by sharing your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have security rules in place you should make sure that auth loads before you attach any listeners. This is covered in a few places in the docs including the [auth recipes section](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/auth.html#loading), and the [queries](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/queries.html#loading) section